# mongodb: how to get the last N records for a each item in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to identify the last N record for a group of items that reside in the same collection.

For example:

Collection name is foo

in the collection, there is a object call bar.

Collection foo:

```
{
{bar: "apples"
prices: 10.8,
create_date: 12345678},
{bar: "apples"
prices: 12.8,
create_date: 12345679},
{bar: "apples"
prices: 12.8,
create_date: 12345680},
{bar: "oranges"
prices: 12.8,
create_date: 12345680},
{bar: "oranges"
prices: 15.8,
create_date: 12345681},
{bar: "oranges"
prices: 2.8,
create_date: 12345682}
}
```

This gets me the second last record for apples.

```
db.foo.find({ 
    "bar" : "apples"
}).sort({ 
    "create_date" : -1.0
}).skip(1).limit(1);
```

But if i want to return apples and oranges in the same record set and get the second last created_date value of each, how can i do this in on single query?

This is my expected output:

(which is basically returning the second value for apples and oranges:

```
{
{bar: "apples"
prices: 12.8,
create_date: 12345679},
{bar: "oranges"
prices: 15.8,
create_date: 12345681},
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output. please show sample output..

Comment: I would like to get the second last item for each bar